# ng-repeat not binding from database

Tags: angularjs, database, data-binding, mean-stack

I have a 1 page application which should display a list of objects from a database.  I used ng-repeat to create a template to bind data from array in db. As I am new to Angular any help would be great.  My code is below:

```js
SERVER.JS

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('eventlist', ['eventlist']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/eventlist', function (req, res) {
  console.log("i received a get request")

  db.eventlist.find(function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
  });
});


app.post('/eventlist', function (req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  db.eventlist.insert(req.body, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
  });
});

app.delete('/eventlist/:id', function(req, res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  db.eventlist.remove({_id: mongojs.ObjectID(id)}, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
  });
});

app.get('/eventlist/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  db.eventlist.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
  });
});

app.put('/eventlist/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.body.name);
  db.eventlist.findAndModify({
    query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
    update: {$set: {name: req.body.name, startDate: req.body.startDate, price: req.body.price, location: req.body.location}},
    new: true}, function (err, doc) {
      res.json(doc);
    }
  );
});


app.listen(4000);
console.log("Server running on port 4000");
```

```html
INDEX.HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/page.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>Capstone Project</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Carnival and Event Mapping tool">

    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="overlay"></div>

      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
          <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
              <li class="sidebar-brand">
                  <a href="#">
                     Brand
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Enter Zip Code</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <input type="text"/><button>Submit</button>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Events Near Me<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Select Radius</li>
                  <li><a href="#">5 Miles</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">10 Miles</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">15 Miles</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Ascending</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Descending</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="mailto:theapp@somemail.com">Contact</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

      <!-- Page Content -->
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
          <button type="button" class="hamburger is-closed" data-toggle="offcanvas">
              <span class="hamb-top"></span>
        <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
      <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <h1>Summer Event List</h1>

        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="event.name"></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="event.startDate"></td>  <!--type="date" (put this next to startDate)-->
              <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="event.price"></td> <!--$<input type="number" name="currency" min="0" max="9999" step="0.01" size="4"
    title="CDA Currency Format - no dollar sign and no comma(s) - cents (.##) are optional" />-->
              <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="event.location"></td>
              <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addEvent()">Add Event</button></td>
              <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deselect()">Clear</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="event in eventlist"> <!--also tried ng-repeat="event in eventlist track by $indexs"-->
              <td>{{event.name}}</td>
              <td>{{event.startDate}}</td>
              <td>{{event.price}}</td>
              <td>{{event.location}}</td>
              <!-- <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(contact._id)">Remove</button></td>
              <td><button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="edit(contact._id)">Edit</button></td> -->
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script src="controllers/controller.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
  </html>


  </div>
   <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->


   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
   var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
       overlay = $('.overlay'),
      isClosed = false;

     trigger.click(function () {
       hamburger_cross();
     });

     function hamburger_cross() {

       if (isClosed == true) {
         overlay.hide();
         trigger.removeClass('is-open');
         trigger.addClass('is-closed');
         isClosed = false;
       } else {
         overlay.show();
         trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
         trigger.addClass('is-open');
         isClosed = true;
       }
   }

   $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
         $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
   });
   });
   </script>

</body>

</html>
```

```js
CONTROLLER.JS
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");

var refresh = function(){
  $http.get('/eventlist/').then(function(response) {
    console.log("I got the data I requested");
    $scope.eventlist = response;
    $scope.event = null;
  });
};

refresh();

  $scope.addEvent = function () {
    console.log($scope.event);
    $http.post('/eventlist/', $scope.event).then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
      refresh();
    });
    $scope.update = function() {
      console.log($scope.event._id);
      $http.put('/eventlist/' + $scope.event._id, $scope.event).then(function(response) {
        refresh();
      })
    };
  };

  $scope.remove = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
    $http.delete('/eventlist/' + id).then(function(response) {
      refresh();
    });
  };

  $scope.edit = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
    $http.get('/eventlist/' + id).then(function(response) {
      $scope.event = response;
    });
  };


  $scope.deselect = function() {
    $scope.event = null;
    refresh();
  };

  }]);﻿
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it as **`response.data`**,

```
var refresh = function(){
  $http.get('/eventlist/').then(function(response) {   
    $scope.eventlist = response.data;
    $scope.event = null;
  });
};
```